# The recruiter is asking me to wait for the interview because they are having a delay even though they had already advertised the vacancy

Tags: communication, recruitment

A recruiter is asking me to wait for an interview because they are having a delay and they are waiting for a confirmation by their client about the start date and the number of candidates.

But they had already advertised the vacancy and had contacted me twice in a period of 3 weeks. Sometimes with a delay so and I had to contact them and send a follow-up email. How should I respond now? I don't know how much time they need to continue the process.

I know that they were honest and told me the real reason for the delay but this seems a bit disorganized to me.

**Should I show that this may affect my interest about the job or say that I will wait till they know? Does this seem that I am as always available to take their call?**

Comment: "Should I show that this may affect my interest about the job?" - what exactly did you have in mind? Even if you grumble, it sounds like you'll still have to wait if you want the interview.

Comment: Presumably you are interviewing for other vacancies elsewhere at the same time (if were looking for a new job, I wouldn't be putting all my eggs in one basket).  So wait for the interview, and if you're offered something else in the mean time consider taking it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not necessarily that they lied to you. Sometimes in business, things change between when the job is first advertised and when they start to fill it. (See the US federal government hiring freeze put in place by the Trump admin as an example. Also many many contractor positions are currently on hold as well.) I have been through processes that took months before they even called and more months afterwards.  There is nothing odd going on here at all. Don't bother waiting for them though, keep looking.

Comment: I see. I am glad they were honest. They are human beings. Ofc they might have a delay and it is OK for me. But It is just the whole situation which made me have second thoughts. They are posting this job regularly the past 6 months.  Plus they actually told me about the delay because I contacted them again after we had a scheduled phone call which I never received it. Anyways I will keep searching and just tell them when they have any further info to contact me.

Comment: Yep, went on an interview back in October that took a month to set up. By the time I came in they shuffled the teams, and the interview ended up being for a testing position rather than a straight up developer position. Miscommunication on their part and a bit on the recruiter, but they still liked me and indicated they'd absolutely hire me if they had a dev position open. Sucks it didn't work out, but I ended up with some good vibes at a company I wouldn't mind working for in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Never stop looking for a job just because you have one company looking at you.

You want to have 3 or 4 companies interviewing you if possible.

As for this company, tell them the truth.  If the delay really affects your interest, tell them -- but do not be surprised if they stop calling you.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal.  They rush to get resumes in front of a client, who's stated that they have positions to fill immediately.   Then, the client reviews resumes, and at the point of further activity they discover internal budgeting or logistics issues and push back.  There's nothing you or the recruiter can do but wait things out.  Sometimes, the opportunities just fizzle.

"Hurry and wait" is how you might describe this process.

Don't get stuck on it.  It's a real downer, but I'd suggest you keep looking elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. The weird thing is that they are posting this vacancy again and again the last 6 months. I saw it at least 3 times reposted. So maybe this isn't the first time the "hurry and wait"  has happened.

Comment: At first opportunity, you should ask why it's that way.  You don't want to sign up for a mess!